# Will my application run IPhone 4 or lesser version?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, xcode4.6

I am newbie to the IOS application development. I developed an app using UICollectionview controller and coverflow animation. I saw the UICollectionview is new addition to IOS 6.0. If that is the case, will my app runs on IPhone 4 or any previous models?

Thanks in advance,
Abilash.G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the device will have iOS 6 or later it will run on that without any case. But if device will have version lower than 6.0 then it will create a problem on there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed. In terms of devices iOS 6.0 is supported for iPhone 3GS and later, iPod touch 4th generation or later and iPad 2 or later.

Answer (score 1):

If that iPhone has iOS 6 installed, it will run just fine.